# some codes don't work. i dont know why. how can i make the codes work?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication, methods

I wanna make Login screen in unity. I'm gonna use firebase, and followed the manual in firebase page and some youtube channel to learn how to use firebase.

and.. some codes don't work. I used the codes that firebase give, and the codes that are below login success don't work. um.. sorry for my weak English. please see the codes. thanks.

this codes don't work

```c#
authUI.ShowLoggedInPanel();// 로그인 성공 시 메인메뉴로 전환!
authUI.LoggedInUserEmail.text = newUser.Email;
```

I don't know what i can try..

```c#
private void TryLoginWithFirebaseAuth(string email, string password) // 기존 사용자 로그인
{
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => 
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        // 로그인 성공 (Maybe Login success?)

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

        authUI.ShowLoggedInPanel();// 로그인 성공 시 메인메뉴로 전환!
        authUI.LoggedInUserEmail.text = newUser.Email;
    });
}
```

It doesn't show the error to me. but just.. it doesn't work.
Could someone help me out here.

Comment: What exactly `doesn't work`? You say you see no errors .. what happens instead?

Comment: oh,,   i mean...   i wanna change the panel to LoggedInPanel what i create, and the method(ShowLoggedInPanel()) have that codes. but it doesn't work.  not that codes, but all of codes what are in that position?(location?) doesn't work.  So.. i mean... i think the codes stop working at that position(below Debug.Logformat(~)).

Comment: But you see the Debug.Log displayed? Have to tried setting breakpoints and debug the execution line by line? Could you add the content of the method `ShowLoggedInPanel`?

Comment: yes I saw Debug.Log displayed. and the next codes doesn't work.  And surely I added the content of the method ShowLoggedInPanel ...  I don't understand why it doesn't work.. I wrote the codes as exactly same with a youtuber's codes. His codes work well (including changing scene) but why not mine?

Comment: Wait if you are speaking about changing scene .. is it possible that the panel and text out are changing simply are in the old scene and therefore not visible anymore after switching to another scene?

Comment: ah... um... i mean changing 'panel' not changing'scene'. sorry i choose wrong word. And.. the reason why i said the codes stop working there is that all of my tries didn't work. I tried putting a method from in the class or other class, and a invoke method, etc.. but nothing is work or show me exception or error.  it always show me 'User signed in successfully:  (gc3MFRmi65WsuNMtDZxwdCi5YRF2)' message

Comment: if the Debug.Log works fine it sounds very strange to me that any other method shouldn't be called there as well. Did you try to move the Debug.Log or add additional logs in between and after the method calls?

Comment: omg...  I switch the position 'Debug.Log(~)' and 'authUI.ShowLoggedInPanel();', then the Debug.Log doesn't work. i cant see the message anymore. what is the reason?

Comment: I don't know since I can't see the content of `ShowLoggedInPanel()`

Comment: the issue might also be that `ContinueWith` is not executed in the main thread but in a background thread ... which is not possible for Unity API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Firebase well but the issue might be the threading.

All (the most) Unity API calls have to be done in the main thread. Since Firebase executes its stuff async in a background thread some calls might simply fail.

You should rather use an `Action` parameter in order to pass a callback to the method like e.g.

```c#
private void TryLoginWithFirebaseAuth(string email, string password, Action<Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser> successCallback) // 기존 사용자 로그인
{
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => 
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        // 로그인 성공 (Maybe Login success?)

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;

        successCallback?Invoke(newUser);
    });
}
```

and use it like

```c#
TryLoginWithFirebaseAuth(someName, somePassword, onSuccess =>
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            onSuccess.DisplayName, onSuccess.UserId);

        authUI.ShowLoggedInPanel();// 로그인 성공 시 메인메뉴로 전환!
        authUI.LoggedInUserEmail.text = onSuccess.Email;
    }
```

this makes sure it is definitely executed in the Unity main thread.

Comment: I failed...  i should find another way hahaha. Anyway thank you for help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to definitely answer your question without more context around it (ex: are there any useful logs in the Unity console?).

Some things to note:
You have to make sure you've setup Authentication in the Firebase Console. This means clicking Authentication in your side bar and explicitly enabling the methods you want:
[image: Enable Authentication]

Similarly, you need to make sure that your applications are properly setup. Your package id/bundle id (Android/iOS) need to match what's in your console. Similarly, you need to upload the SHA1 of your signing certificate to get it to work in Android.

I'm assuming that you're just debugging for now, so you can get your debug certificate here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

You'll want to open up project settings: [image: project settings]

And add your fingerprint there:
[image: add fingerprint]

Following up on @derHugo's suggest, threading may be an issue in addition to the basic setup instructions above. I wrote a post recently on how to work with threading and Firebase in Unity here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html

The easiest way to make your code thread safe would be to replace `ContinueWith` with `ContinueWithOnMainThread`. This is an extension method on Task provided by the Firebase plugin to make it easier to work with.

I hope that all helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic Task continuation problem in Unity using Firebase. When you use, `ContinueWith` it is not ensured to be called on the main Unity thread. What you're trying to do `authUI.ShowLoggedInPanel();authUI.LoggedInUserEmail.text = newUser.Email;` requires to be executed on the Unity main thread. If you try to access GameObjects inside `ContinueWith`, that will fail. The code just ghosts out without any error in the console.

The solution:
Instead of `ContinueWith`, use [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) from [Firebase extensions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) which was made exactly for this reason.